# Excel Macro that reads the number of rows in another spreadsheet and fills down formulas

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two spreadsheets. One of them contains a lot of data with each column titled a few times, so the actual data for each column ends up starting in row 4 and on. In my other sheet (Note: they are in the same excel file though), I have some of the columns titles, a formula in row 3, and then the output of my formulas from rows 4 and on. Essentially, I have made formulas that check certain columns and the information in them for each row that there is data. What I want to do is have a button macro that looks at how many rows of data there is in that first spreadsheet starting at row 4, and then automatically have my formulas in the second sheet fill down to that certain amount of rows.

I have attempted to write the macro, but I end up getting a run-time error. Here is the code:

```
Range("A4:S4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A4:S" & Cells(Row.Count, "Core Data2!A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

A-S are the amount of columns I have in my formula sheet. Core Data 2 is the spreadsheet with all the data

If someone could please show me how to get this to work, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code for each of the columns A to S:

```
Range("A4:A" & Sheets("Core Data2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=[INSERT FORMULA HERE]"
```

In this example, A is the column that will be 'autofilled' up to the amount of rows populated with data in column A of the 'Core Data2' sheet.

Comment: I tried doing this:    Range("A4:A" & Sheets("Core Data2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(EXACT('Core Data2'!E4,'Core Data '!E4),"True","Difference in Pre-Population Information")" but it says I have an expected end statement when it hits the "True" in my formula @user2696883

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is going wrong? It seems as if you are comparing the String in a field to that exact same field (cell E4 of Core Data2). If that's the case, it's always bound to be true.

Comment: It is comparing the same cell in two different data sheets. It's a formula that checks if data has been updated at all once given to another source. If you look closely its Core Data2 and Core Data. The problem could be where I typed in my formula after your macro maybe? It gives me a compile error when I type that exact code in the first comment, and when I go to debug it highlights the "True" part.

Comment: Apologies - I missed the difference in worksheet names. Add a double inverted commas to the True and Difference in Pre-Popupation Information. For example ""True"" rather than just "True".

Comment: Thank you so much, been stuck on this for so long. I knew it was something weird that needed to be done.